# Using NgRef on downgraded Angular 5 component in AngularJs 1.7.2

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-directive

I am working on a project in Angular 1.7.2 that utilizes some components that were built in Angular 5/6. We are downgrading the components using the [downgradeComponent](https://angular.io/api/upgrade/static/downgradeComponent) tool and everything is working just fine.

We recently added a new component that we need to integrate with but we need to access the components properties as well. I was looking into the [ngRef](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRef) directive but that does not seem to be working and I'm unable to find any other ngRef examples outside of the Angular documentation. When I add the ngRef and bind it to a variable in the current scope, it never gets assigned. Any help would be appreciated!

**Angular 5 component**

```
export class ImportedComponent implements OnInit {

    variable1: boolean = true;
    variable2: boolean = false;

    constructor(private certService: ImportedComponent) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.variable1 = true;
        this.variable2 = false

    }
}
```

**Html - w/ AngularJS 1.7.2**

```
<imported ng-ref="importedProperty" ></imported>

<custom-button ng-if="importedProperty.variable1"  [disabled]="!importedProperty.variable2"></custom-button>
```

**Downgrading**

```
angular
  .module("blah", [])
  .directive(
    "imported",
  downgradeComponent({ component: ImportedComponent }) as angular.IDirectiveFactory
  );
```

The downgrading for the imported component is working because the HTML is showing up and I'm able to see the console.log()s occurring from their end but when I try to access `importedProperty`, I get undefined (or empty object if I initialize it as such in my scope prior)

Comment: What are you doing to make sure that the code accessing `importedProperty` has waited for the `<imported>` component to initialize. If the code attempts to access the `importedProperty` too early, it will see `undefined`.

Comment: The `<custom-button>` component mixes AngularJS syntax with Angular syntax. How does that work?

Comment: Right now not much is being done to wait for that component to be initialized (I'm working on adding some waiting operations for that now to see if that resolves the issue).

As for the `<custom-button>` - it is also a angualr 5 component which is being downgraded similarly to the `importedProperty`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up working with the component owner who is now passing the data back as an event. I then listen for that event and use those properties accordingly